# Изменение класса сущности Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

В общем, при разработке проекта возник вопрос, о том, как изменить **класс сущности** связанный с БД (добавить поле, удалить поле и т.д.) и обновить базу данный с сохранением предыдущих данных.
Допустим, есть класс игрока, в котором присутствуют 2 поля. Эти два поля сохранены в бд. Затем к классу добавляется еще одно поле, при этом данные в бд, тоже должны обновиться с сохранением значений предыдущих двух и добавлением значения по умолчанию 3 поля.
Хотелось бы узнать существуют ли встроенные средства в Hibernate, либо увидеть самописный метод решения.
Если это важно, то я использую БД **H2** вместе с **Hibernate**.
P.S. Приводить код не вижу смысла, так как все описано в вопросе.
P.S.S. Привожу доп. информацию.
Допустим у меня есть класс игрока

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email", unique=true, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
    public String email;

    public String password;
}
```

И это сущность привязана к бд. В процессе разработки, у меня накопилось около сотни таких строк в таблице и к этому времени мне стало необходимо добавить какое-либо поле к классу сущности, допустим так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email", unique=true, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
    public String email;

    public String password;

    public String nickname;
}
```

И мне нужно как то обновить таблицу, добавив в её строки новое поле(со значением по умолчанию для этого типа), при этом сохранив данные старых полей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вам нужно сделать называется [миграция данных](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration), т.е. изменение схемы БД или самих данных, когда меняется приложение. Хороший обзор проблемы и подходов к решению можно почитать [тут](https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) (на английском).

Вкратце суть такая, что вместе с новой версией приложения поставляется некий скрипт, который делает изменения в БД, так чтобы привести БД в состояние, которое новая версия приложения ожидает.

Этот скрипт запускается как один из шагов обновления приложения.

Для управлениями этими скриптами (их часто называют просто миграциями) используется инструмент, который иногда пишут сами, иногда используют готовый. В зависимости от этого сам скрипт может быть разным по форме (это может быть просто sql файл с командами, или некая конфигурация, например, в xlm или yaml, которую использует этот инструмент, и там прописаны грубо говоря шаги "добавь колонку Х в таблицу У").

Этот инструмент должен, как мининимум, отслеживать какие изменения в структуре уже пременены и позволять применять те, что еще не пременены. Так же он может помогать создавать миграции, анализируя например текущее состояние БД и сравнивая его с моделями hibernate в данном случае.

Сам хибернейт не имеет хорошей встроенной системы для миграций, которая годится для использования в проде.

Если говорить о других готовых инструментах, то сейчас два довольно популярных это [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) и [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org). Полезно будет почитать [сравнение](https://www.liquibase.org/liquibase-vs-flyway).

В liquibase есть [расширение](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki), которое позволяет генерировать миграции по изменениям в моделях.

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`, но если вы захотите
обновить уже существующее поле, данные будут потеряны